# jTDS driver for SQL Authentication from Linux

Tags: jtds

I am using jTDS driver for MSSQL server windows authentication from Linux. However, I am getting the below error. What am I missing?

```
Driver version is 1.3.1. Connection URL : jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname:1443/dbname;instance=instance;useNTLMv2=true;
```

The error I am getting is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:654)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at jTDS.MSSqlTestConnection.main(MSSqlTestConnection.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: GSS Failed: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1976)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)
        ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jTDS.MSSqlTestConnection.main(MSSqlTestConnection.java:21)
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, were you able to make it work ?

Comment: No. It is very complex. We have created some local workarounds for that